# Accelerating Graphics rendering in STM32F7

Tags: stm32, ltdc

I have a framebuffer that is created on SRAM with LTDC that is everything is written to that buffer, images, icons,..etc. and get displayed to the LCD screen. That works fine.
but the screen size is 320*240, I overclocked the CPU, but still when the framebuffer is cleared, I see some slowness, it doesn't clear the buffer that fast.

I'm thinking about DMA2D, but how would that work in my case ? I have just a single buffer that I'm writing data to it, and I would like to copy it to LTDC hardware that fast.

Comment: Why do you need to clear the framebuffer? (you can only store 32 bits at the time anyway, this is a hard limit by hardware)

Comment: How do you "copy the data to the LTDC"? Usually, the LTDC directly accesses the buffer, no need for any copying.

Comment: @Jeroen3 To clear a screen for drawing next frames, the buffer has to be cleared

Comment: @Erlkoenig I'm not copying any data, I'm just refeering to the framebuffer address

Comment: You usually don't clear the buffer, but just overwrite it with the new data. Also, most applications have 2 (or even 3) buffers, feed one to the LTDC while rendering a new image on the other one, and swap pointers in the LTDC-frame-done-interrupt.